# How to return an superclass object in a subclass's instance method?

Tags: java, oop

The following is a toy problem of my original problem. `Bird` is an interface. `Cardinal` is the subclass of `Point` and it implements the `Bird` interface. The `Aviary` class carries out the implementation.

**Question:** What should I put in the `getPosition()` instance method such that the `Aviary` class carries the `getPosition()` method correctly?

Please correct me if the abstract method in the `bird` interface is coded wrong.

```
public interface Bird{
    public Point getPosition();
}

public class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;

 // Constructs a new Point at the given initial x/y position.
    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

// Returns the x-coordinate of this point
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    // Returns the y-coordinate of this Point
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}
```

Question is in the following code:

```
public class Cardinal extends Point implements Bird{

    // Constructors
    public Cardinal(int x , int y){
        this(x,y);
    }

     // not sure how to write this instance method
     public Point getPosition(){
        ???????????
    }

}

public class Aviary{
       public static void main(String[] args){
                Bird bird1 = new Cardinal(3,8);
                Point pos = bird1.getPosition();
                System.out.println("X: " + pos.getX() + ", Y: " + pos.getY() );
       }
}
```

Comment: In getPosition(),write:  return this

Comment: Why is a `Cardinal` a `Point`? Shouldn't a `Cardinal` instance instead use a `Point` instance variable to keep track of its location? It'd be pretty surprising if code expecting a location got a bird.

Comment: Is a `Cardinal` a `Point`? This is the typical question to ask to check if inheritance makes sense. On the other hand, it makes complete sense to say "A cardinal has a position which is a point." This implies that it makes more sense to use composition instead. To do this, simply add a `Point` member variable to your `Cardinal` class. Better yet, make `Bird` an abstract class with a `Point` member variable since **every** bird has a position.

Comment: Using composition will also make the answer to your more immediate question incredibly obvious.

Comment: Hi, I am new to Java. Please elaborate on composition. Thanks. I am happy to learn new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the object itself:

```
public Point getPosition(){
    return this; // returns a Point object
}
```

---

I gave an answer, but I am not sure if you have a design nightmare or a one-of-a-kind design simplification. A `Point` subclass implementing a `Bird` makes me bang my head on the wall, but having both types in one object will make the calculations pretty neat, (if you have massive calculations, that is). Because instead of `bird.getPosition().getX()`, you can write `bird.getX()`.

```
Point bird1 = new Cardinal(3, 8);
Point bird2 = new Cardinal(4, 12);

// calculate the distance between two birds
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bird2.getX() - bird1.getX(), 2) + Math.pow(bird2.getY() - bird2.getY(), 2));
```

But if your system is not a bird simulator that needs heavy calculations on birds represented by mere `Point` objects, I think you should use composition over inheritance.

```
public interface IBird {
    public Point getPosition()
}

class Bird implements IBird {
    private Point position;

    public Bird(int x, int y) {
        this.position = new Point(x, y);
    }

    public Point getPosition() {
        return this.position;
    }
}

// and then in main()
Bird bird = new Bird(3, 8);
Point pos = bird.getPosition();
System.out.println("X: " + pos.getX() + ", Y: " + pos.getY() );
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes a lot more sense now. And you made me realise I shouldn't use inheritance blindly.

Answer (score 2):

The `Cardinal` class objects have an *is-a* relationship with the `Point` class objects, so you could just `return this;` as Krumia suggested.

P.S. you can use the `super` keyword when referring to a superclass within a subclass to access it's **protected** and **public** methods.